# What Maven Artefact holds PowerMock.mockStaticPartial?

Tags: java, maven, mocking, mockito, powermock

A few Powermock/Mockito articles mentioned use of a `PowerMock.mockStaticPartial` method - the only problem is I can't find it anywhere!

Does anyone know which artifact and version this exists/existed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely in v1.4.11 of powermock-api-easymock see [powermock-api-easymock-1.4.11.jar](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/powermock/powermock-api-easymock/1.4.11/powermock-api-easymock-1.4.11.jar!/org/powermock/api/easymock/PowerMock.class?classDetails=ok) for Maven/Ivy details and a view of the .jar itself.

The Maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
   <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.11</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are using Mockito as well, you should be aware of the version compatibility between Mockito and PowerMock, see http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13 for which versions work together.

Answer (score 1):

I think this method is since [API 1.2](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.2/apidocs/org/powermock/api/easymock/PowerMock.html). Check the [PowerMock wiki](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/GettingStarted) Maven setup, there are the dependencies for each of it's parts. The dependencies are version 1.4.12 so they should include *mockStaticPartial*.